# Where are the waters of Yodeya?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I'm very interested in finding some Yodeya water. Is it possibly a river or lake? Was it perhaps (as I saw in another answer) named after someone named Yodeya?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I think this might belong as a Meta PTIJ question

Comment: I think that  those who don't speak or read Hebrew well or at all, would miss the pun intended in this question. I also VTC, b/c if this is a Purim question, it needs the disclaimer. Besides, this, I think that you will need to edit the question so that people get the pun, here.

Comment: Edited to include disclaimer.

Answer (score 3):

The waters of Yodeya are available everywhere on this site. Torah is compared to water, and the majority of this site discusses and teaches Torah.

There are a few caveats, though:

- Not all questions have water, such as those closed b/c they violate some policy of this site.
- Purim Torah questions, such as this one have funny or weird tasting water, so choose to drink this stuff, wisely. Also, be aware that such water is available only for about 2 weeks per year.